# Problem installing snapd

Tags: software-installation, application-development, programming, python-2.7

I like to install snapd
but my computer say message like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package snapd
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: snapd is only in the default repositories for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install snap
```

Comment: On Mint 13

> "Package snap is not available, but is referred to by another packaged. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source."

Comment: `snap` is not `snapd`.

Comment: I get that error when I try to install snap via apt-get. The answer does not help. Sorry.